# Azure VS Online Continuous Deployment Missing Assemblies

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, msbuild

When linking an Azure website to a VS Online solution for continuous deployment not all of the dependencies are being deployed. Specifically the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll` assembly which is being used to automatically version a database on startup.

The solution being built contains a MVC web application and two class library projects that the web application references. The `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll` assembly is referenced by one of the class libraries and under usual Visual Studio building gets copied (along with it's dependencies) to the web applications' build folder.

When deploying to Azure (using the `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml` template) the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll` assembly and it's dependencies are ignored. This remains the case even if they are directly referenced and used in the web application project. The copy local flags are correctly in the project file.

I really need to figure out how to get this working as I'm sure it shouldn't be this hard?

Comment: I think I have a similar issue (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131640/azure-continuous-deployments-issue). Did you find a solution to your problem?